# Error in running t-test via stat_compare_means function, and TukeyHSD

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, ggpubr

For the "rd" parameter, I got an error message while running t.test using the `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()` function. Moreover, TukeyHSD analysis of my data categorized all the individual group as "a", implying that there was no significance differences. This seems a bit weird as I'm expecting the opposite by looking at the plot (attached  [my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miGkL.png)). Moreover, there was no issue for identical t.test and TukeyHSD analysis of other parameters (fv,fq,npq, and in_situ etc. in data frame ). Please find my scripts and datas below, thanks.
This was just an example of similar plot from another parameter ("fv" in data frame) where the results of t.test from `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()`were shown above the error bars,identical script was being used here. [expected plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFWcv.png)

```
Exp1 <- read_csv("Raw data/Exp1.csv")
Exp1 $time <- factor(Exp1$time)
Exp1 $growth_condition <- factor(Exp1$growth_condition)
summary_anti_PsbS_both <-summarySE(data=Exp1, measurevar="rd", groupvars=c("time","growth_condition"))

> data.frame(Exp1)
   id   growth_condition time   fv   fq  npq in_situ    rd
1   1            Control    0 0.81 0.56 0.72   0.797 1.000
2   2            Control    0 0.81 0.58 0.78   0.788 1.000
3   3            Control    0 0.80 0.59 0.76   0.793 1.000
4   4 High light+Chilled    0 0.82 0.57 0.85   0.799 1.000
5   5 High light+Chilled    0 0.81 0.59 0.75   0.796 1.000
6   6 High light+Chilled    0 0.81 0.56 0.69   0.782 1.000
7   7            Control  0.5 0.81 0.53 1.08   0.759 1.279
8   8            Control  0.5 0.81 0.56 0.72   0.759 0.668
9   9            Control  0.5 0.79 0.50 1.04   0.771 0.877
10 10 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.70 0.46 1.04   0.540 0.487
11 11 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.60 0.43 0.69   0.652 1.341
12 12 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.73 0.46 1.19   0.606 0.904
13 13            Control    8 0.82 0.52 1.20   0.753 0.958
14 14            Control    8 0.81 0.55 1.09   0.759 0.642
15 15            Control    8 0.80 0.55 1.07   0.747 0.612
16 16 High light+Chilled    8 0.44 0.28 0.58   0.230 0.471
17 17 High light+Chilled    8 0.35 0.21 0.45   0.237 0.777
18 18 High light+Chilled    8 0.54 0.35 0.68   0.186 0.342
19 19            Control   24 0.81 0.49 1.17   0.762 0.915
20 20            Control   24 0.82 0.67 1.25   0.749 0.876
21 21            Control   24 0.82 0.48 1.18   0.756 0.836
22 22 High light+Chilled   24 0.40 0.25 0.45   0.089 0.392
23 23 High light+Chilled   24 0.43 0.27 0.51   0.106 0.627
24 24 High light+Chilled   24 0.34 0.21 0.37   0.140 0.258
25 25            Control   48 0.81 0.48 1.05   0.773 0.662
26 26            Control   48 0.80 0.45 1.14   0.785 0.914
27 27            Control   48 0.82 0.47 1.09   0.792 0.912
28 28 High light+Chilled   48 0.73 0.45 0.90   0.750 0.800
29 29 High light+Chilled   48 0.70 0.51 0.79   0.626 1.305
30 30 High light+Chilled   48 0.66 0.43 0.74   0.655 0.579
```

Script for plot

```
ggplot(data=summary_anti_PsbS_both, mapping = aes(x = factor(time), y = rd, fill= growth_condition))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  labs(x= "Time (hr)",  y="Relative density", fill= "Growth conditions")+
  ylim(0,1.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=rd-se, ymax=rd+se), width=.2, position=position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
  annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=1.45, label="n=3")+
  stat_compare_means(data=Exp1, label="p.signif", label.y= 1.35, method="t.test")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Error message

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`:
Problem while computing `p = purrr::map(...)`.
```

Script for TukeyHSD

```
res.both88 <- aov(rd ~ growth_condition * time, data =Exp1)
summary(res.both88)  
t8<-TukeyHSD(res.both88)
multcompLetters4(res.both88,t8)
```

Comment: What you’re asking isn’t very clear. What was the error message? How did you produce these plots if there was an error? Where is the code and output for your Tukey test? Why are you surprised there were no significant differences when your plot shows overlapping error bars? What is the “expected plot” you included?

Comment: @zephryl thanks for the reply, i've edited the question to make it more clear. I was thinking of error bars overlapping too while deciphering the TukeyHSD results, now that makes sense. However, there's still one issue, I can't run the t.test for "rd" using this script- stat_compare_means(data=Exp1, label="p.signif", label.y= 1.35, method="t.test"), while there's no issue for the other parameters (fv etc.)